# How to implement a search bar in the appBar for a gridview list in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i have a grid View with title for each one, i want to implement a search bar in the appBar, i've been search for the web but couldn't found something to work with,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can `addListener` for `TextEditingController` when search text change return `searchList`

code snippet

```
final TextEditingController _searchQuery = TextEditingController();
...
_searchQuery.addListener(() {
      if (_searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = false;
          _searchText = "";
          _buildSearchList();
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = true;
          _searchText = _searchQuery.text;
          _buildSearchList();
        });
      }
    });
... 
List<Model> _buildSearchList() {
    if (_searchText.isEmpty) {
      return _searchList = _list;
    } else {
      _searchList = _list
          .where((element) =>
              element.name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
              element.title.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      print('${_searchList.length}');
      return _searchList;
    }
  }
...
GridView.builder(
            itemCount: _searchList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return GridItem(_searchList[index]);
            },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Model {
  String id;
  String name;
  String title;

  Model({this.id, this.name, this.title});
}

class SearchList extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchList({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SearchListState createState() => _SearchListState();
}

class _SearchListState extends State<SearchList> {
  Widget appBarTitle = Text(
    "Search Demo",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  );
  Icon actionIcon = Icon(
    Icons.search,
    color: Colors.orange,
  );
  final key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final TextEditingController _searchQuery = TextEditingController();
  List<Model> _list;
  List<Model> _searchList = List();

  bool _IsSearching;
  String _searchText = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _IsSearching = false;
    init();
  }

  void init() {
    _list = List();
    _list.add(
      Model(id: "1", name: "name 1", title: "a title 1"),
    );
    _list.add(
      Model(id: "2", name: "name 2", title: "a title 2"),
    );
    _list.add(
      Model(id: "3", name: "name 3", title: "b title 3"),
    );
    _list.add(
      Model(id: "4", name: "name 4", title: "b title 4"),
    );
    _list.add(
      Model(id: "5", name: "name 5", title: "b title 5"),
    );
    _searchList = _list;

    _searchQuery.addListener(() {
      if (_searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = false;
          _searchText = "";
          _buildSearchList();
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = true;
          _searchText = _searchQuery.text;
          _buildSearchList();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: key,
        appBar: buildBar(context),
        body: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: _searchList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return GridItem(_searchList[index]);
            },
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
            )));
  }

  List<Model> _buildSearchList() {
    if (_searchText.isEmpty) {
      return _searchList = _list;
    } else {
      _searchList = _list
          .where((element) =>
              element.name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
              element.title.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      print('${_searchList.length}');
      return _searchList;
    }
  }

  Widget buildBar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: appBarTitle,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.orange),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: actionIcon,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                  this.actionIcon = Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Colors.orange,
                  );
                  this.appBarTitle = TextField(
                    controller: _searchQuery,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search here..",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  );
                  _handleSearchStart();
                } else {
                  _handleSearchEnd();
                }
              });
            },
          ),
        ]);
  }

  void _handleSearchStart() {
    setState(() {
      _IsSearching = true;
    });
  }

  void _handleSearchEnd() {
    setState(() {
      this.actionIcon = Icon(
        Icons.search,
        color: Colors.orange,
      );
      this.appBarTitle = Text(
        "Search Demo",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      );
      _IsSearching = false;
      _searchQuery.clear();
    });
  }
}

class GridItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Model model;
  GridItem(this.model);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 7),
      elevation: 10.0,
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.orange,
        onTap: () {
          print(model.id);
        },
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 18.0 / 11.0,
              child: Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    this.model.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 14.0),
                    maxLines: 1,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 0.0),
                  Text(
                    model.title,
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SearchList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, how can i also make a different inkwell (on tap) for each element of the gridview, to navigate to separate pages ?

Comment: In GridView.builder, You can wrap GridItem with Inkwell.

Comment: forgive me but i'm pretty new at it, i tried to do it but this will only navigate to the first page for all cards, what i want to do is add a route for each item to navigate to different pages, (for example name 1 will take me to page 1 and name 2 to page 2)

Comment: Sorry to insist but if it's possible a working example will really help

Comment: I have answered in your new question. please check it.